# SQL: selecting things ONLY associated with one value

Tags: sql

Ok so i'm trying to write a query that returns duplicate values ONLY if they are in the same column and associated with one particular value.

So say for example there are 5 apples in a database, but 1 of them is associated as 'red' whilst the other are 'green', none of the apples would be returned in a query selecting fruits with only one association. However if there were 4 apples in another database and all of them were only associated with 'red', then all of them would be returned in a query selecting fruits with only one association. Assuming there are only 2 different values, red and green.

So my query would look like this:

```
SELECT Apples
FROM Fruits
WHERE Colour = 'RED' AND Colour NOT IN (SELECT Apples FROM Fruits WHERE Colour =    'GREEN')
```

My query doesnt run or return the results i need, how do i return values only associated with a single value?

Can anyone help out?

EDIT: okay i didnt use an effective analogy, i'm only trying to get values that are associated with only one value. Check my comment to see the better analogy i used

Comment: So, you want the query to return all rows from the table if all rows are `'Red'` and no rows at all if just one row is not `'Red'`?

Comment: @PaoloFalabella wow, you were half a second faster!

Comment: I commented on your "new" analogy to see if I understand it now, can you comment on this?

Comment: I just tried the edited query. It looks right but i just get an error box with a yellow caution symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand your question correctly, you want a list of all fruits (with the same name/title) returned, only if there is only one kind of color for that , otherwise you want none in your results.

This looks a bit dirty using a subquery but is the best I could come up with in short time:

using this table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Fruits (Id INT PRIMARY KEY auto_increment, Title VARCHAR(63), Colour VARCHAR(63));

INSERT INTO Fruits (Title, Colour)
  SELECT 'Apple', 'Green'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 'Green'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 'Blue'
  UNION
  SELECT 'Orange', 'Yellow'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Orange', 'Yellow';
```

You can perform this query

```
SELECT
    Id
  FROM Fruits AS OuterFruits
  WHERE
    Title = 'Orange'
    AND
    (
      SELECT
          COUNT(Colour)
         FROM Fruits AS InnerFruits
         WHERE
          InnerFruits.Colour != OuterFruits.Colour
          AND InnerFruits.Title = OuterFruits.Title
    ) = 0;
```

This will give the rows of the two oranges inserted, if you however where to replace `'Orange'` with `'Apple'` in that last query you would get an empty result set, because there are different colours of apples available.

You can try that online in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4f51/2) also.

Please note that this is mysql-syntax (since you did not include any special sql version, but I'm pretty sure only `auto_increment` is mysql-specific)

Comment: so, to clarify (again on the fruits example) we have fruits with different ids, but they can share a title (like "apple" or "orange") so apple can have id 1,2 and 3, where id1 is red, id2 is green and id3 is green then you would not want that result set to contain anything, but if all ids with title "apple" had the same colour you would want them in the result set, is that right?

Comment: yeah pretty much, the fruits example is ambiguous since obviously there are more fruits with different colours, but in my example there are only two "colours" and many "fruits". my dvd analogy is simpler.

Comment: So you want to search by movienum or search by format? from what you last wrote I imagine you want to search by format...

Comment: is this more like it? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4f51/2 you can replace `Orange` with `Apple` here to see different results for different titles or in your movie db movienums.

Comment: Search by format, So it should basically be like
SELECT Movienum
FROM Copies

Comment: look at my last comment/fiddle

Comment: YES! YOU MAGNIFICENT AMAZING PERSON IT WORKED, THANK YOU

Comment: Oh wait, i jumped the gun. A list of movienums was retuned and on first glance it was right, but it's only half right, there are 3 or 4 incorrect movies in there. Weird.

Comment: oh noes? In that case I think we could need some of your test data to reproduce that, or maybe you missed something when replacing column and table names in the query?

Comment: actually only 2 movies. And they are the only single copy. Does this mean i should change the value of of "= 0;" at the end? the incorrect movies are the only ones that have only one copy and that one copy is blu-ray

Comment: only one copy would be still valid in the above query, but you only want records where there are more than 1 occurance AND of only one type? then this fiddle should come close, i included another single value `Banana` that is not being retrieved if searched by: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40dbc/9

Comment: close, i want records where there are more than but including 1 AND of only one type (blu-ray). your new edit came close but cut out correct answers. your first one actually worked better. i really do appreciate you helping me through this

Comment: so if there is only one record you do not care if it is actually the format you searched for? you search for dvd, but want blue-ray anyways if there is a movie that has only one copy and that is blue-ray (again if searching for dvd???)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37180/discussion-between-drcopypaste-and-user2368457)